# ListView Scaling Across Multiple Resolutions

Tags: android, listview, android-constraintlayout

[Pixel 2 XL vs Nexus 5x](https://i.stack.imgur.com/suO7o.png)

I am trying to scale my custom ListView across multiple resolutions, but I am running into this problem: I have extra white space on the Pixel 2 XL, which is a 1440p device, but it looks fine on the Nexus 5X, which is a 1080p device.

Attached is XML code that I have for both the Fragment and the ListView. I am using a ConstraintLayout on the fragment, and a RelativeLayout for the ListView. I have tried using a ConstraintLayout for the ListView, but I had trouble anchoring my 2nd text view to the right side.

ListView XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="68dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="310dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:gravity="end"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Fragment XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/frameLayout2"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".LeaderboardFrag">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/leaderboardListView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: just a curious, why are you still using listview, use recyclerview its better.

Comment: I did not know about RecyclerView at the time. And I created a custom ListView Adapter for this listview, so its just easier to keep it currently

Answer (score 0):

Setting up

```
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
```

will put your ListView in the center always.
Try removing

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the following changes

Listview XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="68dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="310dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:gravity="end"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Fragment XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/frameLayout2"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="your_color"
tools:context=".LeaderboardFrag">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/leaderboardListView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Constraint layout doesnt support `match_parent` so you can do something like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/frameLayout2"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".LeaderboardFrag">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/leaderboardListView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

setting value to `0dp` will allow your layout to match your supplied constraints. Also, its your choice but using `RecyclerView` is better than using `ListView`.